# R psych package - Sort correlation matrix after PCA using mat.sort()

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, principal, psych

After principal component analysis I am trying to get the variables of my original correlation matrix to be sorted in the same way as in the (sorted) loadings matrix (as displayed with print.psych). I have used the following functions from the psych package, but I can't get the two to align.

```
pc <- principal(myCorrMatrix$correlations, nfactors=15, n.obs=49, rotate="oblimin")
print.psych(pc, cut=0.3, sort=TRUE)

sortedPC <- fa.sort(pc)
sortedMatrix <- mat.sort(myCorrMatrix$correlations, sortedPC)
```

I am not 100% sure what the second parameter of mat.sort should be, but i tried several of the elements of sortedPC to no avail. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: would be best if you `dput` your `myCorrMatrix$correlations`, as all the commands you are using are specific to the `psych` package. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @rmk: I understand it would make it easier, but i would prefer not to share the data...

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `fa.sort()` to `mat.sort()`.  `mat.sort()` expects an fa object, which has the $loadings in it.  Note that `principal()` also gives the $loadings in the resulting object.  I think this should work:

```
sortedMatrix <- mat.sort(myCorrMatrix$correlations, pc)
```

Here's an example:

```
data(Bechtoldt.1)
sorted <- mat.sort(Bechtoldt.1,principal(Bechtoldt.1,5))
cor.plot(sorted)
```